Any reason not to use 5/8 drywall to meet 1/2 drywall at corner?
I am installing 1/2in sheet rock in a room; one short wall requires a sheet about 24"x84" to meet 1/2 drywall only at the corners. I have a piece of 5/8in just the right size. (Just to be clear, 5/8 will only meet 1/2 at 90degree corners.)
Two questions:

Is there any reason not to use the 5/8 for this little section?
Does the type of corner (inside or out-) affect the answer?


No reason not to do it. I've done it on longer walls separating bathrooms from bedrooms and have never had any problems with the corners, both types.

No.
You do want to cover one edge with the other size to make mudding a 90 degree corner easier.  So cutting to meet is more important.
Even a butt joint of the two different thicknesses could be done if the mud is feathered out by 12 or 18 inches to make it seem flat in most light conditions.  Might feel it by hand.
